# How to migrate extensions to work with TYPO3 10.x

Tags: typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I'm Looking for a kind of guide how to migrate extensions to work with TYPO3 V10.
I don't find much when I try my luck on google and don't really know where to start.

We are actually using TYPO3 9.5 and I will need to migrate Comsolit's owl_slider which we are heavily using on our website. TER doesn't offer a Version for TYPO3 V10.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not built by you, if an update comes, all of your changes will be overwritten. With that being said, if you decide that you want to update it to TYPO3 10 by yourself then you should first avoid the `"*"` if you are on composer mode and you have to insert the current version so next time you run composer update, composer won't update the extension. Still, composer will check if the extension is compatible with TYPO3 v10 and if not then it will not run. So you will have to remove it from the composer and manually download it to your ext directory. If you are on non composer mode, just avoid clicking the update button in the extension manager.

For Frontend not much have been changed. The most common error that you can get is the `<f:switch/>` viewhleper where the defualt case has been changed from `default="true"` to `defaultCase` [Changes](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.0/Deprecation-73068-DeprecatedDefaultArgumentOnFcase.html).

Now you will have to deactivate the extension and update your TYPO3 installation to v10.

The first thing you need to do is to change the TYPO3 dependency to 10.99.99 or something greater than your current version (ext_emconf.php). From this point on, is try and error. You have to install the extension and go step by step through the errors that appear if any. Here you can find the changes that have been made. It would be wise to avoid deprecated function since in TYPO3 11 or 12, will be removed.

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog-10.html

You can not know rom the start what can go wrong unless you test it. Even if you know exactly what has been changed, you will still need to try and error.

Best regards